# How to create an unordered list using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got a javascript object as follows

```
var course = { 
    chapter: "chapter 1",
    chapter: "chapter 2",
    lesson: "lesson 1",
    lesson: "lesson 2",
    lesson: "lesson 3",
    chapter: "chapter 3",
    lesson: "lesson 1",
    page: "page 1",
    page: "page 2",
    page: "page 3",
    lesson: "lesson 2",
}
```

Now, I want to generate my unordered list as follows:

```
<ul>
    <li>chapter 1</li>
    <li>chapter 2</li>
    <ul>
        <li>lesson 1</li>
        <li>lesson 2</li>
        <li>lesson 3</li>
    </ul>
    <li>chapter 3</li>
        <ul>
            <li>lesson 1</li>
            <ul>
                <li>page 1</li>
                <li>page 2</li>
                <li>page 3</li>
            </ul>
            <li>lesson 2</li>
        </ul>
</ul>
```

How can I achieve that using jQuery or JavaScript. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You cannot have properties with same name in your object.

Comment: Well, to start with, if you wrote that statement what you got was an object like `{chapter: "chapter 3", lesson: "lesson 2", page: "page 3"}`, because an object only stores one value (expect it to be the last one give) for each key.  You need to pick a data structure that will actually hold the value you want, and then you can worry about how to generate HTML from it...  If order really doesn't matter, you could do something like `{"chapter  1": {}, "chapter 2": {"lesson 1": {}, "lesson 2": {}}}` and so on...

Comment: Sorry for that mistake. what I have now is an array of objects fetched from xml, and I can print them all into a single list successfully. Where I am stuck right now is how to show the hirearchy

Comment: JSfiddle here - [https://jsfiddle.net/wa0znz27/1/](https://jsfiddle.net/wa0znz27/1/)

Comment: can you check if the solution is working for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you're able to convert your object data to a simpler array list of content then you can run a block of conditional logic using jquery `each` to cycle through the array and ascertain which list levels each item should be based on its predecessor.

Here is an attempt with the logic commented, I suspect there should be a more elegant way to do this.

```js
var course = [
  "chapter 1",
  "chapter 2",
  "lesson 1",
  "lesson 2",
  "lesson 3",
  "chapter 3",
  "lesson 1",
  "page 1",
  "page 2",
  "page 3",
  "lesson 2",
  "chapter 4",
  "chapter 5",
  "lesson 1",
  "lesson 2",
  "lesson 3",
  "chapter 6",
  "lesson 1",
  "page 4",
  "page 5",
  "page 6",
  "lesson 2"
]; // content

var paper = $('.course'),
  oldlesson = false,
  oldpage = false, // lesson or page flags
  cases = {
    'less': 'lesson',
    'chap': 'chapter',
    'page': 'page'
  }; // list scenarios for later assessment

function addList(level, newcontent) {
  paper.find('ul').eq(level).append(newcontent);
} // content adding function, targets specific levels of ul

$.each(course, function(i) {
  var typ = this.substring(0, 4), // check the first four letters of the list type
    content = '<li class="' + cases[typ] + '">' + this + '</li>'; // estanlish the list class and content
  if (cases[typ] === 'lesson' && !oldlesson && !oldpage) { // is this li a new lesson?
    paper.append('<ul />'); // add a nested unordered list
    oldlesson = true; // we are now in lesson nesting state
  } else if (cases[typ] === 'page' && !oldpage && oldlesson) {
    addList(-1, '<ul />'); // add a new page level ul
    oldpage = true; // we are now in paper nesting state
  }
  if (cases[typ] === 'lesson' && oldpage && oldlesson) { // lesson after page?
    addList(-2, content); // append to the penultimate ul 
    oldpage = false;
  } else if (cases[typ] === 'lesson' && !oldpage && oldlesson) {
    addList(-1, content); // append to the last lesson ul
  }
  if (cases[typ] === 'page' && oldpage) {
    addList(-1, content); // append to the last page ul
  } else if (cases[typ] === 'chapter') { // if it's a chapter then reset all levels
    paper.append(content); // otherwise go about your business adding lists
    oldlesson = false, oldpage = false; // reset list type flags
  }
}); // cycle through array items
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class='course'>

</ul>
```